# How to solve undesirable webrequest call if it is already running with timer?

Tags: c#, timer, httpwebrequest, parallel.foreach

I have a timer as

```
 public static System.Timers.Timer timer_get = new System.Timers.Timer();
 timer_get.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Get_OnTimedEvent);
 timer_get.Interval = 1000;
 timer_get.Enabled = true;
```

It is hitting this method.

```
public static void GetListFromDb()
        {
            try
            {
              DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                //..here is i am filling datatable
                Parallel.ForEach(dt.AsEnumerable(), row => {
                    GetDataFromApi(row);
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //..
            }
        }
```

Each row has irrelevant `webrequest` elements(url,type,etc). I am sending the webrequest method at the same time.

The problem is that that the `webrequest` takes more time than the timer clock with 1000ms resolution above. Running requests are frequently hitting this problem and I don't know how to solve it. Is there any way to detect if a method is already running with a specific parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can identify each request by some key, you can manage a dictionary for "running" requests

```
public static System.Timers.Timer timer_get = new System.Timers.Timer();
private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool> _runningRequests = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool>();
```

And then

```
    static void GetDataFromApi(DataRow row)
    {
        var requestKey = (string)row["Url"];

        if (_runningRequests.TryAdd(requestKey, true))
        {
            try
            {
                //send web request
            }
            finally
            {
                bool alreadyRunning;
                _runningRequests.TryRemove(requestKey, out alreadyRunning);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot. This solve my problem with your simple way.Thiking complex is not good most times :) What a question did i ask that how to detect a method is running or not :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by setting the Timer's AutoReset property to false. This will make sure that your callback will not be re-entered until you manually tell the timer to fire again. This method would work well because Parallel.ForEach will not return until the loop has completed. Here's an example using your code:

```
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        public static System.Timers.Timer timer_get = new System.Timers.Timer();

        public static void Main()
        {
            timer_get.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Get_OnTimedEvent);
            timer_get.Interval = 1000;
            timer_get.AutoReset = false;
            timer_get.Enabled = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Any Key to Exit");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        private static void Get_OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                GetListFromDb();
            }
            finally
            {
                timer_get.Start();
            }
        }

        public static void GetListFromDb()
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                //..
                //..
                //..
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //..
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but i use one timer and n number of webrequest. Stopping timer doesnt effect the other requests ?